# Summations and integrals with no upper limits

Tags: notation

I've seen expressions like:

$$\sum\limits_{i} f(x)$$

And
$$
\int\limits_\mathbb{R}f(x)dx
$$

What does it mean that they have no upper limits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's give an example for summation:
$$
\sum_k \binom{n}{k}(-1)^k \left( 1 - \frac{k}{n} \right)^n
$$
Since $\binom{n}{k}$ is defined as being $0$ except when $0 \leq k \leq n$ this sum is the same as 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(-1)^k \left( 1 - \frac{k}{n} \right)^n
$$
and is neater to write.

By the way, as a softball follow-on question, show that the sum we are talking about is $$\frac{n!}{n^n}$$

As to integrals over $\Bbb{R}$ that just means an integral from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. But I am disturbed by not seeing the $dx$ in the integrand.

Answer (score 1):

The first expression is just plain bad. It doesn't make sense because $f(x)$ has no obvious dependence on the index $i$.

For the second, we're just integrating along the whole real line $(-\infty, \infty)$. We often use the term *improper* to describe such integrals, because they may still be poorly defined, such as if $f(x)$ has a singularity (e.g. $f(x) = 1/x$). We can occasionally settle such issues by being more precise, such as by using the [Cauchy principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value).

Answer (score 0):

The second is clear by itself. It means integrate through the entire $\Bbb R$. The first one need context to explain, usually the author wants to same sum all $i$ as mentioned about, or it is an infinite series.

Comment: @By integrate through the entire $\mathbb{R}$ you mean $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)$?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Yup.

Comment: What if the lower limit is not $\mathbb{R}$? I've seen some expressions like that but can't recall any examples at the moment...

Comment: It doesn't mean "lower limit". Sometimes people put the domain of integral at the bottom. It is convenient when the domain is not subset of $\Bbb R$, for example, a high dimentional ball, usually denoted as $B_r(P)$, where $r$ is the radius, $P$ is the center.

Comment: $\int_{\Omega} f(x) dx$ means " the integral of $f$ over the set $\Omega$"

Comment: @Tryss and how would that be evaluated? Taking the upper limit as the "biggest" element in $\Omega$?

Comment: Forget about the "upper limit". $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ is just a notation for "the integral of f over the set $[a,b]$" (modulo the question of the sign that is a little tricky)

Comment: The reason you keep thinking of "upper limit" and "lower limit" is because of the fundamental theorem of calculus. It applies differently in general, and sometimes it is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

For the first:

When the index set is understood from context, it is often dropped, leaving only the index, as in ∑i i2. This will generally happen only if the index spans all possible values in some obvious range, and can be a mark of sloppiness in formal mathematical writing. Theoretical physicists adopt a still more lazy approach, and leave out the ∑i part entirely in certain special types of sums: this is known as the [Einstein summation convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) after the notoriously lazy physicist who proposed it.

http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/pinewiki/SummationNotation.html#Sums_without_explicit_bounds